# Draw doesn't works with OpenGL while drawing sphere

Tags: c, opengl

I'm first in OpenGL, and i want to draw a sphere with 3D graphical view.

For first step, i just want to draw a belt that contained to result sphere. 
But there's no result, all of my result window is cleared with white.

Is there any problem in my code?

Here is my Code :

```
void init();
void display();
void drawPath(int pi, int theta);
void drawQuad(int pi, int theta);

int we = -80; // - 파이
int kyong = -180; // - 세타

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, (char**)argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutCreateWindow("Prog09 - Goo");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    init();
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}

void init(){
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glOrtho(0, 50, 0, 50, -50, 50);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
void display(){
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    drawPath(0, 0);
}

void drawPath(int pi, int theta){
    drawQuad(pi, theta);
}

void drawQuad(pi, theta){
    int i;
    GLfloat x[4],y[4],z[4];

//    theta = (theta * 3.14)/180;
//    pi = (pi * 3.14)/180;

    x[0] = sin(theta)*cos(pi);
    y[0] = cos(theta)*sin(pi);
    z[0] = sin(pi);

    x[1] = sin(theta)*cos(pi+20);
    y[1] = cos(theta)*sin(pi+20);
    z[1] = sin(pi+20);

    x[2] = sin(theta+20)*cos(pi+20);
    y[2] = cos(theta+20)*sin(pi+20);
    z[2] = sin(pi+20);

    x[3] = sin(theta+20)*cos(pi);
    y[3] = cos(theta+20)*sin(pi);
    z[3] = sin(pi);


    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(x[i]*10, y[i]*10, z[i]*10);
        glEnd();

    }
    glFlush();

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%d. %f %f %f\n",i+1, x[i], y[i], z[i]);
    }
    printf("WHY?\n");
}
```

I know it's a basic question, but i have know idea why my codes doesn't work.
Thanks for your helps.

Comment: I'm not sure where you try to draw a sphere here, so you might want to ask "... while drawing a quad"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are drawing a number of polygons, were each polygon contains exactly one point:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex3f(x[i]*10, y[i]*10, z[i]*10);
    glEnd();
}
```

If you want to draw **one** polygon with **all** the points, then you'll have to do something like:

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    glVertex3f(x[i]*10, y[i]*10, z[i]*10);
}
glEnd();
```

Comment: !! Thanks! You are my code saver! It was too silly question XD
Thanks one more time :)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. The time was not over to mark as accepted answer so i waited for 1 minute, and i just forgot. T.T
Thank you for answering, have a good coding time :)